# Defining A Binary Relation On All Real Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Define a relation R on $\mathbb R$ (Set of all Real Numbers) as follows: For all real numbers $x$ and $y$, $x \mathrel{R} y$ if and only if $x = y$.

Since the set of all real numbers is infinite, how would I create set $R$ (A relation on the set of all real numbers) that satisfies the requirement above without listing out every single number? Thanks!

Comment: It didn't say "create." It said "define." Set theory lets us define infinite sets even though we necessarily can't list all the elements.

Comment: I would assume you might be expected to just define $R$ as $R=\{(x,x);x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Is the first paragraph here supposed to be an exercise? And how sure of that are you? In the usual mathematical way of phrasing things, that text ("Define a relation .... $x=y$.") is not asking the reader to _do_ anything -- on the contrary those words _are_ a complete definition of $R$.

Comment: Yup, DRF and Sloan got it. Thanks to Thomas for clarifying that for me. And Henning, yes I made a mistake.

Comment: How do you create the set of all even integers, or the set of all rational numbers without listing every single one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Try $R=\{(x,x) | x \in \mathbb{R}\}.$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I didn't consider that. That would be a reflexive relation, correct?

Comment: @Roger it would even a an equivalence relation, in fact $R$ is the well-known relation "$=$" (as could be expected from the definition $xRy\iff x=y$)

Comment: So the relation would still be reflexive and symmetric though, right?

Comment: Yes, it is trivially reflexive and symmetric.